# How do I submit a form with parameter values in MVC5 C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, form-submit

How do I submit a form with parameters values in C# MVC5? I have tried with the below example but it does not properly route to the controller action.

@Html.ActionLink("Submit Visit", "EditSubmit", "Home", new { warLineItemId = @ViewBag.WarLineItem.Id, customerNumber = @ViewBag.customerInfo.Number, warId = @ViewBag.WarId } , new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right" })

Comment: public ActionResult EditSubmit(int warId, int customerNumber, int warLineItemId)
        {   NameValueCollection nameValueCollection = Request.Form;
             WarLineItemManager.Save(warLineItemId, warId, WarLineItemManager.GetMemberInformation().UserName, nameValueCollection);
            Session["Success"] = "WAR Successfully Submitted  !!!";
            return Json("success", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

Comment: Please read [ask], then [edit] your question and format your code (indent by 4 spaces, or use the `{}` button). Don't add comments to clarify, [edit] your question instead. As is, your question is unreadable. Please also include what you mean by "doesn't get submit". Any errors (in the server logs)?

Comment: Remove AJAX tag as they are not using ajax, formatted code and cleaned up question

Answer (score 0):

does you method in the home controller resemble:

```
 public ActionResult EditSubmit(int warLineItemId , string customerNumber, int warId)
    {}
```

I guessed the value types, since you didn't post them.